# Can I define a const static instance of a class in the class header file

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare and define a const static instance of a class in the class header file.

I want to do something like this (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647186) similar question):

```
class PlaceID {

public:

    inline PlaceID(const std::string placeName):mPlaceName(placeName) {}

    const static PlaceID OUTSIDE;

private:
    std::string mPlaceName;
};

const PlaceID PlaceID::OUTSIDE = PlaceID("");
```

This would work if the definition of PlaceID::OUTSIDE was in a source file, but if it's in a header file that is include in multiple location it causes an link error because PlaceID::OUTSIDE is then defined multiple times.

I'd like to define it in the header file for two reasons. First, this will be part of a library and I'd like the library to be header file only.

Second and this is the most important one I want the compiler to be allowed to "inline" the uses of this instance. The class in question (not the one used as an example here) is a wrapper around a primitive type with all methods inlined in order to offer the same performance as the primitive type would. If I place the definition of this instance in a source file, the compiler will not know it's value at compilation time and won't be able to apply some optimisations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, variables can be marked as `inline`:

```
class PlaceID 
{
    inline const static PlaceID OUTSIDE{""};
    // ...
};
```

---

Before C++14, you can use a function instead:

```
class PlaceID 
{
    static PlaceID OUTSIDE() { return PlaceID{""}; }
    // ...
};
```

...or...

```
class PlaceID 
{
    static PlaceID OUTSIDE() 
    { 
        static PlaceID result{""};
        return result;
    }

    // ...
};
```

...depending on whether or not you want a single `PlaceID` instance.

---

Alternatively, you can templatize `PlaceID` over a dummy parameter in order to inline the definition of `OUTSIDE` in an header:

```
template <typename>
struct PlaceID_
{
    inline PlaceID_(const char*) { }
    const static PlaceID_ OUTSIDE;
};

template <typename T>
const PlaceID_<T> PlaceID_<T>::OUTSIDE{""};

using PlaceID = PlaceID_<void>;
```

This works because templates are implicitly `inline`. See [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work) for more details.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o2oD2USL2aJ4ykMi)

---

Also consider marking `PlaceID::PlaceID(const char*)` as `constexpr` if possible so that `OUTSIDE` can be marked `constexpr` as well. Obviously this will not work if you decide to use `std::string`.

Comment: I like the use of a function. I'll test if it "inlines" it.

Comment: @MathieuPagé: see updated answer, added another technique

Comment: Why the additional `inlined` wrapper? Wouldn't `template <class = void> const static PlaceID OUTSIDE{""};` work the same?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo woops, that makes sense. `template <typename T = PlaceID> const static T OUTSIDE{""};` does work though (provided that the constructor is `constexpr`, which is needed anyway).

Comment: @Quentin: I actually screwed up, I've updated the answer with what I really wanted to achieve

Comment: ... yuck! Here, the upvote is yours. I'm glad we have actual inline variables now...

Answer (score 0):

> that is include in multiple location

You can stop your header from being included multiple times(and causing your problem(DISCLAIMER: I have not tested it.)) by this(which is commonly used by a lot of libraries)

`a.hpp`

```cpp
#ifndef LIBRARY_A
#define LIBRARY_A
//define other things
#endif
```

replace `LIBRARY_A` for an ID of your choice(note it can't conflict with other libraries so avoid names like `SOUND_SYSTEM`, but rather `SOUND_LIBRARY_FOO` with `FOO` replaced by your project name/your name)